# Has anyone used Blender for prototyping animations of mobile apps?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, interface-design, mobile, blender

After Effects and other Mac only tools are popular among designers for prototyping animations of mobile apps. I wanted to know if there's anyone here who uses Blender for prototyping?

If you do use could you tell me your workflow and experience with it?

Comment: What does Blender (I do not know this program)? What does the manual tell you? What tried you and where and what is your problem using this software?

Comment: After Effects isn't Mac only...

Answer (score 3):

3D Applications, like Blender, Maya, Modo etc. are as good as After Effects for mocking up things like this.  Perhaps better in some regard, although typography is typically easier in After Effects. 2 dimensionality is after all just a subset of 3D. Slap in a orthographic camera and you are set

You may need to work on the workflow a bit upfront. So saving out some nice models of buttons and animation key frames/expressions will speed up your workflow for future projects too. But this applies to any software.

I used to do this a lot, though personally I avoid blender. But since I am not using any features that do not exist in blender same applies to blender, as it does to modo, Houdini and 3dsMAX

[image]

**Image 1:** Quick and dirty mockup of a possible mockup (10 min from scratch) done in Maya. I'm in a bit of hurry so no time to refine this. Works equally well in blender.

**PS** after effects is not a mac only app.