# How are the animations of these vector art type made?

Tags: vector, inkscape, animation

I have seen animations on what looks like vector art to me [here](https://dribbble.com/shots/2887107-ADWEEK-Addressable-TV) and [here](https://dribbble.com/shots/2858288-Cats-man).

[image]

[image]

In fact I have seen some very complex scenes having ~100 objects, all animating independently (in what looked like proper physics) around creating great visual spectacle!

I am a newbie to vector graphics (using InkScape) and amused by how such nice animations are done.

Are they -

1. Done by programming libraries (Saw some svg manipulating libs in JavaScript, but that looks tedious to do such peculiar animations like glass filling with liquid)
2. Done in some movie creating software ?
3. By hand (frame-by-frame) in Vector Graphics editing software ? (Looks really time consuming)
4. Something else ?

or my understanding is wrong and they infact are not vector graphics itself ?

Comment: 3 first question have one answer. Yes. Movie creating software have programming libraries where you can correct them by hand frame by frame. 
Flash (or Animate) can do all these things and allow you to program additional things for your need.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I dont see why the something else can not have the answer Yes.

Comment: @joojaa I couldn't think about how else you could do it.

Comment: I think both animations can be (and probably are) done with SVG animation. The second one could be a candidate for After Effects, Edge or similar, but quite honestly I see this just as SVG manipulation, I don't see anything complex or too time consuming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Possibly the first demo (the cat) is a very good candidate for such things. However, its probably done in a animation software.
2. Most probably in some animation software. Such as *After Effects*, *Adobe Animate*, *Flash*, *Toonboom Harmony* etc. Even most 3d animation software would work well (I could make the cat in Maya in about 10-15 minutes, including tooling up, much faster in Harmony).
3. Animation is always time consuming no matter what you do. Software helps, but animation has a horribly high learning curve. Even animating by hand is not as time-consuming as you think, in context of animation always being time consuming.

   [image]

   **Image 1**: A quick thing I made frame by frame for fun in 15-20 minutes of a [post on engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/2959/1324) using [illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55807/how-to-do-animation-frame-pngs/55809#55809)

   So for example the cat could be made by hand quite quickly Id say about less than 20 minutes (It is a simpler animation than the rotation but not much). All you need to do is resign the nagging idea that there might be a better way.
4. Something else? What would that something else be, stop motion animation?

Comment: 4. Something else could be a 3D animation with a toon / outline shader

Comment: @Luciano Ive included that in software, because,  3D or not its still animation software is software ignore the 3rd dimension or not. All 3D is capable of 2D thats given.

Answer (score 1):

Like joojaa said, you can create it in a 3D animation software like Blender:

- Design a 3D object like the one you have drawn in 2D,
- color it in a way that looks 2D,
- animate it with the camera looking at the object in a 2D plane.

See also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiqrCRqyLzE&list=PL1gEYuY5m72Y_cFfa6Rolbt7PHA4V6eJ8).