# creating animation in illustrator or photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, animated-gif

I have this vector drawing of an iceberg that I want to create a simple animation where a blue gradient is animated moving in place the current black outlines. Since the end result would be to use this for Android, I would need it to be a series of frames. Is there a way to get this automatically done or does it have to be manual creation?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Illustrator has no animation features.  Photoshop can create simple frame by frame gif animations. It's not automatic though.   Some automation is certainly possible using actual animation software, such as Blender, or AfterEffects. But questions on these are generally off-topic here. Perhaps try Video Production Stack Exchange for AfterEffects questions, or Blender Stack Exchange for Blender questions.

Comment: This *could* be done in Photoshop with a simple TImeline animation and a mask. But *how* would require a full blow tutorial and that's not what this site is about. You should A) pick an app and then B) explore the animation features in that app to learn the basics. Animation is *rarely* automated entirely. At a minimum key frames are configured then tweening is automated.

Comment: I've made [an attempt](https://gist.github.com/bananu7/0ce5776fc1806acbaadd17c93be69e83) to do that with just HTML and CSS. It seems to work fine, but to automate grabbing frames from it i think it'd be easier if it was an SVG.

To explain my approach a bit - using inverted multiply (called screen) gives you an ability to take the black part of the mountain and pick up the gradient. Then you animate the gradient behind completely separately.

Comment: it is possible to make animations in illustrator. after all i do it, but its a bit tricky. See: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55807/how-to-do-animation-frame-pngs/55809#55809  anyway try aftereffects.

Comment: ...there's also the export to SWF in Illustrator.. or at least there used to be.. not sure if it's still there in 2023.